# Overloading the stream insertion operator with strings

Tags: c++

I've been reading this book but still not 100% clear on the concept. So, please pardon me for asking such a trivial question as my only intention is to learn the basis right and not spam with trivial and/or duplicate questions.

I checked for related questions, but couldn't find the answers to my questions.

So, here goes:

This is the code snippet that is being referred to:

```
//s1 and s2 are objects of the std::string class

cout << "s1 is \""
     << s1
     << "\"; s2 is \""
     << s2
     << '\"';
```

This is what the author has to say about it:

`We now output these two string objects, using cout and operator
<<, which the string class designers overloaded to handle string objects.`

Now then, overloaded? Does he mean that it's being overloaded as to accept two different arguments (string objects - s1/s2 and string literals - the stuff in " ") and perform the same function? Is my understanding right? Is that all it's getting overloaded with?

Comment: Checkout [operator overloading](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators).

Comment: If you don't want to spam, research first.  Search StackOverflow for "c++ operator <<".

Answer (score 1):

In very brief, the built-in `<<` means to left-shift an integral type.

The standard library provides an overloaded version of `<<`, that when given a stream (`cout`) and a string (`s1`, etc) will properly print the string to the screen.

I do *highly* recommend picking up a book from the book list: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Your answer clarifies everything. The link provided by R Sahu will be helpful but not the ideal response to the answer I was looking for. Thank you Mark B.

Comment: Can you provide me such a definitive book guide and list for Java as well, if possible?

Comment: I'm reading this C++ book by Dietel and Dietel. Is it bad?